# Append to cell if validation list value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add an additional '-' sign to the value in the Hours column if the status is changed from 'Pending' to 'Completed'.

I tried the "Worksheet_Change" event but I do not see any changes in my worksheet.

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C14")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Intersect(Range("C5:C14"), Target)
        .Offset(, -1).Value = -.Offset(, -1).Value
        .ClearContents
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me, Is this code in the relevant sheet module? Type `?application.enableevents` in the immediate window and you should get back True.

Comment: @SJR Yes, it is. When I entered that into the immediate window, I'm getting a False instead of True

Comment: @SJR Yes, it is in the relevant sheet module, but when I run  `?application.enableevents` in the immediate window I'm getting a False instead of True.

Comment: So in the IW type `application.enableevents=true` and it should work.

Comment: Note that if your code errors it may exit before you reenable events which may have caused the problem you had. One thing to allow for in your code is multiple cells being changed in which case either exit sub or loop through Target.

Comment: @SJR ah, yes it's working now. So does this mean that every time I want to get this working I have to enable it in the IW?

Comment: That said, you would have got an error so probably events were disabled for some other reason. You should not have to reenable it every time, but do take on board my previous comment.

Comment: @SJR alright, i'll take a look at it again thanks!